# C++ virtual method overload/override compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a little program in C++ and I what to play with polymorphism.
So the code goes like this:

```
//Base.h
class Base{
    public:
        void method(const objectType1& stuff1); 
        //objectType1 is whatever type you what (int, string, ...)

    protected:      
        Base(void);
        virtual ~Base(void);

        virtual void method(void) = 0;
};

//Derived.h
/*FINAL - DO NOT INHERIT THIS CLASS OR YOU WILL die :)*/
class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        Derived(void);
        ~Derived(void);

    private:
        void method(void);
};


//Main.cpp
int main(){
    objectType1 ot1;

    //this code works
    Base *bd = new Derived;
    bd->method(ot1);

    //this dosen't
    Derived *dd = new Derived;
    dd->method(ot1); 
    // he doesn't call Base::method(const objectType1& stuff1),
    // he calls Derived::method(void)

    return 0;
}
```

I've solved the problem by renaming the virtual method `void method(void)` in something else and all is well.

My questions are:

- Why doesn't the compiler know to call the method from the base class?
- And why do I see `void method(void)` in `main` since it is declared as `protected` in `Base` and `private` in `Derived` ? (is this some sort of side effect)

Thanks :) .

Comment: You tagged your question `compiler-errors`, so, _what are the compiler errors_?

Comment: yes, `compiler-errors` tag is not exactly correct.

Answer (score 3):

The member method in the base class is public, which means that any piece of code can call it. Besides being public, it is virtual, which means that the execution will be dynamically dispatched at runtime to the final overrider.

Access to the method is checked *statically* in the static type of the reference/pointer through which the call is dispatched, even if it will be *dynamically* dispatched.

On the other hand in the second case, the call is through the derived type, and the access specifier is checked at that level, where the compiler finds the member function to be `private` and thus complains.

In plain english, when the object is used as a base, it behaves as a base, but when used directly it behaves as derived.

Answer (score 1):

The method definition in `Derived` hides the definition in `Base`. To avoid that, add `using Base::method;` to `Derived`.

This happens because when calling functions in `Derived`, the compiler looks into `Base` only if it didn't fine the name in `Derived`. Note that it doesn't look for the *signature* but only for the *name* in that stage. Overload resolution based on the signature is done only afterwards. This is actually not much different to the following situation:

```
void function(int);
void function();

int main()
{
  void function(); // this declaration hides *both* global declarations
  function(3); // error
}
```

In your case `Base` plays the role of the global scope and `Derived` the role of the function scope.

Also note that this is not related to virtaul fgunctions; indeed the same would happen without `virtual` (except that you then couldn't call `Derived`'s `method` via a pointer to `Base`, of course, but would call the `Base` version instead).

Comment: The terminology is incorrect. The method in derived *overrides* (same signature as a virtual method in the base type), not *hides* (either different signature or non-virtual method in the derived type will hide a member function in the base type.

Comment: The method both hides *and* overrides. Hiding is a name lookup feature and comes into play when calling on an object of static type `Derived`. Overriding is a run time feature and comes into play when calling on an object of static type `Base` but dynamic type `Derived`.